How to use pywebview loading screen example
The pywebview docs have a lovely example of an HTML loading screen that can be found at https://pywebview.flowrl.com/examples/loading_animation.html. I was hoping to use this as the loading screen while a dash app that I've written and plan to display using pywebview loads, but it looks like the HTML persists indefinitely. Does anyone know how I can show the loading animation but show the app once it's loaded? My pywebview version is 5.3.2.
Here's the code I have so far:
from dash import Dash, html
from flask import Flask
import webview

server = Flask(
    __name__,
)

app = Dash(
    __name__,
    server=server
)

html_load = """
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #333;
            color: white;
            font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .main-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 90vh;
            display: flex;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            align-items: center;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .loading-container {
        }

        .loader {
          font-size: 10px;
          margin: 50px auto;
          text-indent: -9999em;
          width: 3rem;
          height: 3rem;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background: #ffffff;
          background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
          background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
          background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
          background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
          position: relative;
          -webkit-animation: load3 1.4s infinite linear;
          animation: load3 1.4s infinite linear;
          -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
        }
        .loader:before {
          width: 50%;
          height: 50%;
          background: #ffffff;
          border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          content: '';
        }
        .loader:after {
          background: #333;
          width: 75%;
          height: 75%;
          border-radius: 50%;
          content: '';
          margin: auto;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          right: 0;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes load3 {
          0% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
          }
          100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
          }
        }
        @keyframes load3 {
          0% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
          }
          100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
          }
        }

        .loaded-container {
            display: none;
        }

    </style>
    <body>
      <div class="main-container">
          <div id="loader" class="loading-container">
              <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
          </div>

          <div id="main" class="loaded-container">
              <h1>Content is loaded!</h1>
          </div>
      </div>

      <script>
          setTimeout(function() {
              document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none'
              document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'block'
          }, 5000)
      </script>
    </body>
"""
app.layout = html.Div("THIS IS TEXT!")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    webview.create_window(
        "App Name",
        url=app.server,
        html=html_load,
    )
    webview.start()

